# How to short this statements

Tags: javascript, arrays, addeventlistener

How to short this code and which array method i can use here. I want to add class on every click on a single element and rest of elements remove class.

```
 const activeLink = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item");
 activeLink[0].addEventListener("click", () => {
  activeLink[0].classList.add("active");

  activeLink[1].classList.remove("active");
  activeLink[2].classList.remove("active");
  activeLink[3].classList.remove("active");
});

activeLink[1].addEventListener("click", () => {
  activeLink[1].classList.add("active");

  activeLink[0].classList.remove("active");
  activeLink[2].classList.remove("active");
  activeLink[3].classList.remove("active");
});

activeLink[2].addEventListener("click", () => {
  activeLink[2].classList.add("active");

  activeLink[0].classList.remove("active");
  activeLink[1].classList.remove("active");
  activeLink[3].classList.remove("active");
});

activeLink[3].addEventListener("click", () => {
  activeLink[3].classList.add("active");

  activeLink[0].classList.remove("active");
  activeLink[1].classList.remove("active");
  activeLink[2].classList.remove("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then looping through all items per click, you can just keep track of which item is currently active and reset this one.

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-northcutt-50ucp?file=/src/index.js

```
let activeLink = null;

document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item").forEach(navItem => {
  navItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (activeLink) {
      activeLink.classList.remove("active");
    }
    navItem.classList.add("active");
    activeLink = navItem;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding and give me a effective good snippets. Thanks a lot, i also tried another approach

for (let i = 0; i < activeLink.length; i++) {
  activeLink[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    activeLink[i].classList.add("active");
    console.log(activeLink[i]);
    for (let j = 0; j < activeLink.length; j++) {
      if (activeLink[i] !== activeLink[j]) {
        activeLink[j].classList.remove("active");
      }
    }
  });
}